# How to calculate the integration of $\tanh^{6}(x)\cdot\text{sech}^{4}(x)$

Tags: integration

How to calculate the integration of $\tanh^{6}(x)\cdot\text{sech}^{4}(x)\,$?
$$\displaystyle\int \tanh^{6}(x)\cdot\text{sech}^{4}(x)\mathrm{d}x\,$$
I tried to calculate it by parts but I don't know which function is $u$ and which is $dv$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}$Try using a substitution and hyperbolic identities. Note that $1-\tanh^2 x = \sech^2 x$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(\tanh{x}) = \sech^2 x$.

Comment: If you want to use parts, you'll get some ideas form [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed), but substitution is definitely preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\tanh ^{-1}(t)$ which makes
$$I=\int \tanh ^6(x) \text{sech}^4(x) \,dx=\int t^6 \left(1-t^2\right)\,dt$$

Comment: What will be the final answer?